# In Java, are anonymous inner types detrimental to performance?

Tags: java, performance

Is using anonymous inner types detrimental to performance (CPU utilisation, compiler performance, memory consumption, etc.) as opposed to declaring it explicitly somewhere?
I am using a framework that demands the usage of certain inherited classes, in my case I need the class only a single time and to avoid making the programs flow difficult to follow I'd like to use the anonymous inner type. "object.SetXclass(new ???" will be called often and in any case a new instance of the object inheriting from y needs to be created.

1) explicit class declaration

```
class x extends y
{
    @Override
    public void m() { ... };
}
```

~~

```
object.SetXclass(new x());
```

2) anonymous inner type -is this bad for performance?

```
object.SetXclass(new y()
{
    @Override
    public void m() { ... }; 
});
```

Comment: You're creating a new class either way, so I don't really see how they would differ. The anonymous type is in fact compiled to its own `.class` file, so I'd actually be surprised if there were a difference.

Comment: "The anonymous type is in fact compiled to its own .class file" I didn't know that and now that you told me I guess that answers my question already (;

Comment: Take a look at the folder where your `.class` files end up -- you'll see something like `<class_name>$1.class`, `<class_name>$2.class`, etc. for each anonymous type that was compiled. You can try decompiling them to be sure.

Comment: There *is* (IMHO only) one important difference: In the case of an anonymous inner class, the instance holds a reference to the enclosing instance. However, this should not affect the performance.

Comment: @Marco13: It's a legitimate concern.  It could affect what is eligible for garbage collection.

Comment: @MarkPeters It *could* not only affect what is eligible for GC, but it **does** - definitely. Although this might, theoretically, have an impact on performance (e.g. when GC has to work harder due to memory pressure), it's probably not what the asker was refering to. So to say: There is no "direct" effect on performance, i.e. no "additional indirection", and no "additional allocation cost" or so.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The java compiler compiles anonymous inner classes into their own class files, and the java run time environment then treats the class just as any other class would be treated so there should not be any significant drop in performance.  Here are some references on inner class files http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/java-ent/jnut/ch03_13.htm

Answer (score 1):

An anonymous class saves you having to give the class a name, and pass arguments to a constructor for later use, and it works the same way.

Generally speaking, you should worry about performance, when you have a profiled a realistic test and your measurements indicate you have a problem.  Even if you have been performance tuning systems for decades, you can guess at things which might be causing a problem, but when you measure the code you can find that some thing (possibly many things) are far more significant.